# Python Beautiful Soup - web scraping Clinicaltrials.gov obtaining NCT numbers from search results w/ over 100 results

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a list of clinicaltrials.gov URLs along with a brief description of a project.  My program will obtain the NCT numbers, which are also added to a base URL to make the full clinical trial profile page.  For example, "NCT00471926" added to the end of "https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/" will take you to a full profile from which the brief description is obtained.  This all works fine, except when I have more than 100 results.  In the URL I provide below, there are 216 results. I can scrape the first 100 with my script, but that's it.  Alternatively, I could download all 216 results into a CSV file and import each NCT, but that's not practical to do each week.  Is there a way I can (1) find a way to get all 216 results through web scraping or (2) write code to download my results? For #2, it looks like Javascript is used, so I can't do this (to my knowledge) with Beautiful Soup. Thanks in advance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import lxml.html

out = []
allncturls = []

# get nct numbers first and put into list
ncturls = ['https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=diabetes+quality+improvement&cntry=&state=&city=&dist=']
for ncturl in ncturls:
    response = requests.get(ncturl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    for v in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile('ct2/show/NCT')):
        ext_url = str(v).split()
        for z in ext_url:
            sub = 'NCT'
            z =("\n".join(s for s in ext_url if sub in s))
            z = z.split(':')[0]
            z_length = len(z)
        nct_number = z.split()[1]
        nct_url = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/'+nct_number
        allncturls.append(nct_url)

urls = allncturls
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    abstract = re.sub('\n+|\xa0','',soup.select_one('.ct-body3:contains("Brief Summary:") + div').text.strip()) if abstract == '' else abstract
    data = {'url': url, 'abstract': abstract}
    out.append(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(out)
    df.to_excel('clinicaltrialstresults.xlsx')
```

Comment: Just glancing at the privacy policy of that site makes it seem like scraping that website is a grey area. Doesn't explicit prohibit, but doesn't implicitly accept scraping. Scrape at your own risk.

Comment: Good call - I emailed them specifically and asked if it was allowed and they said "You can web scrape, however if we get multiple requests within seconds, we will block your IP." I've been taught when in doubt, ask for permission (re: web scraping).

Comment: Can you clarify what content you wish to specifically scrape on the page? Is it the data under the `Tabular View` tab?

Comment: Just the default view (Study Details) and really just the detailed summary. To get this far, you'd already have the URL (the other piece of data I need).  More than anything, I'm hoping I can even get the URLs for those that don't appear in the first 100 results without having to download the results into a .csv file.  Thanks!

Comment: getting all the urls is doable in three requests. However, the detailed requests would require a further 216 requests. Would you imagine issuing in batches of say 10 with a pause?

Comment: That would be doable.  In fact, for some of the other scraping I do, I usually do 5 seconds between each request when I have more than 10 requests (if this isn't specified in the robots.txt).  I'm about to hit the sack, but I just wanted to glance at the code below. Looking forward to trying it out tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

The following gets all the links and shows a structure for making requests to all links. The data for the initial links (the first 3 requests have the 216 items basic info stored in json in turn stored in `json_items`; for later access. In the loop over all urls to get detailed summary you need to determine how you are going to pull all info together. I have not run for more than one request. Requires bs4 4.7.1+ though I can easily alter the css selector if that is required.

```
import requests, math
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Referer': 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=diabetes+quality+improvement&cntry=&state=&city=&dist=',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

data = {
  'draw': '3',
  'columns[0][data]': '0',
  'columns[0][name]': '',
  'columns[0][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[0][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[0][search][value]': '',
  'columns[0][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[1][data]': '1',
  'columns[1][name]': '',
  'columns[1][searchable]': 'false',
  'columns[1][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[1][search][value]': '',
  'columns[1][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[2][data]': '2',
  'columns[2][name]': '',
  'columns[2][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[2][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[2][search][value]': '',
  'columns[2][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[3][data]': '3',
  'columns[3][name]': '',
  'columns[3][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[3][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[3][search][value]': '',
  'columns[3][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[4][data]': '4',
  'columns[4][name]': '',
  'columns[4][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[4][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[4][search][value]': '',
  'columns[4][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[5][data]': '5',
  'columns[5][name]': '',
  'columns[5][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[5][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[5][search][value]': '',
  'columns[5][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[6][data]': '6',
  'columns[6][name]': '',
  'columns[6][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[6][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[6][search][value]': '',
  'columns[6][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[7][data]': '7',
  'columns[7][name]': '',
  'columns[7][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[7][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[7][search][value]': '',
  'columns[7][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[8][data]': '8',
  'columns[8][name]': '',
  'columns[8][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[8][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[8][search][value]': '',
  'columns[8][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[9][data]': '9',
  'columns[9][name]': '',
  'columns[9][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[9][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[9][search][value]': '',
  'columns[9][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[10][data]': '10',
  'columns[10][name]': '',
  'columns[10][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[10][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[10][search][value]': '',
  'columns[10][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[11][data]': '11',
  'columns[11][name]': '',
  'columns[11][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[11][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[11][search][value]': '',
  'columns[11][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[12][data]': '12',
  'columns[12][name]': '',
  'columns[12][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[12][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[12][search][value]': '',
  'columns[12][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[13][data]': '13',
  'columns[13][name]': '',
  'columns[13][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[13][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[13][search][value]': '',
  'columns[13][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[14][data]': '14',
  'columns[14][name]': '',
  'columns[14][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[14][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[14][search][value]': '',
  'columns[14][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[15][data]': '15',
  'columns[15][name]': '',
  'columns[15][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[15][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[15][search][value]': '',
  'columns[15][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[16][data]': '16',
  'columns[16][name]': '',
  'columns[16][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[16][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[16][search][value]': '',
  'columns[16][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[17][data]': '17',
  'columns[17][name]': '',
  'columns[17][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[17][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[17][search][value]': '',
  'columns[17][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[18][data]': '18',
  'columns[18][name]': '',
  'columns[18][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[18][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[18][search][value]': '',
  'columns[18][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[19][data]': '19',
  'columns[19][name]': '',
  'columns[19][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[19][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[19][search][value]': '',
  'columns[19][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[20][data]': '20',
  'columns[20][name]': '',
  'columns[20][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[20][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[20][search][value]': '',
  'columns[20][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[21][data]': '21',
  'columns[21][name]': '',
  'columns[21][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[21][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[21][search][value]': '',
  'columns[21][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[22][data]': '22',
  'columns[22][name]': '',
  'columns[22][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[22][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[22][search][value]': '',
  'columns[22][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[23][data]': '23',
  'columns[23][name]': '',
  'columns[23][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[23][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[23][search][value]': '',
  'columns[23][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[24][data]': '24',
  'columns[24][name]': '',
  'columns[24][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[24][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[24][search][value]': '',
  'columns[24][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[25][data]': '25',
  'columns[25][name]': '',
  'columns[25][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[25][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[25][search][value]': '',
  'columns[25][search][regex]': 'false',
  'start': '0',
  'length': '100',
  'search[value]': '',
  'search[regex]': 'false'
}

json_items = {}
urls = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post('https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results/rpc/5i0yqihHSdCL5Q7Gp61PzwS3ai7GvQ1PxnhzmwoyZiNHm67xW', headers=headers,  data=data).json()
    json_items[1] = r    
    num_results = int(r['recordsFiltered'])
    urls += [f'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/{i[1]}' for i in r['data']]
    num_pages = math.ceil(num_results/100)

    for page in range(2, num_pages + 1):
        data['start'] = str(int(data['start'])+100)
        r = s.post('https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results/rpc/5i0yqihHSdCL5Q7Gp61PzwS3ai7GvQ1PxnhzmwoyZiNHm67xW', headers=headers,  data=data).json()
        json_items[page] = r #store all json in case wanted
        urls += [f'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/{i[1]}' for i in r['data']]

    for count, url in enumerate(urls):
        if count % 10 == 0:  #some form of pause x number of requests
            time.sleep(2)
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        study = soup.select_one('h1').text
        detailed_desc = soup.select_one('.ct-body3:has(#detaileddesc) + .tr-indent2').text
        #do something with detailed desc etc
        break #delete me
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work and ultimately, I was able to use some text parsing and regular expressions to get all URLs and detailed summaries.  However, is there a way to do this without using json? I'll admit I haven't worked with json before, so I don't know what the rules for what appears to be storing data on their server.  Also, I may need to change the search query URL too and it looks like the json is linked just the URL I provided.  Either way, I am super grateful for your response and help!!!

Comment: You adapt data that you post to make a different query. Json as shown above is the way to do it with the least requests.